# why does a string who clearly contains a piece of other, not result in a found hit using .contains()?

Tags: java, string

this program attempts to scan a text file radio music log, and then match the songs to a directory of wav files.  all files are named with the same convention: artist-title, ie: lukebryan-kickthedustup.wav.  i swap the locations of the title and artist using the delimiter feature, which allows for easy comparison to the music log, which is already formatted the same way: title, artist.

now, lets say i'm searching the term "lovingyoueasyza", which is Loving You Easy by the Zac Brown Band... when it reaches the file in the directory with the assigned string "lovingyoueasyzacbrownband", it ignores it, even though it contains that string.  you'll see i'm calling:

```
if(searchMe.contains(findMe))
```

yet it doesn't return a hit.  it *will* return matches if the findMe string *only* contains the song title, but if any part of the artist title creeps into that string, it stops working.  why!?  for shorter titles its critical i be able to search for artist name as well, which is why i can't just search by song title.

i've tried using .trim() to no avail.  here is some sample output of when a match is found:

```
searching term: "onehellofanamen"
comparing to: "onehellofanamendbrantleygilbert"
Match found!
value of findMe: onehellofanamen
value of searchMe: onehellofanamendbrantleygilbert
value of y: 49
value of x: 79
```

here is sample output of a failed attempt to match:

```
searching term: "lovingyoueasyza"
comparing to: "keepmeinminddzacbrownband"
searching term: "lovingyoueasyza"
comparing to: "lovingyoueasydzacbrownband"
searching term: "lovingyoueasyza"
comparing to: "nohurrydzacbrownband"
searching term: "lovingyoueasyza"
comparing to: "toesdzacbrownband"
searching term: "lovingyoueasyza"
```

this is what the findMe's go into the method as:

```
fileToProcess var is: C:\test\06012015.TXT
slot #0: topofhouridplac
slot #1: lovemelikeyoume
slot #2: wearetonightbil
slot #3: turnitoneliyoun
slot #4: lonelytonightbl
slot #5: stopset
slot #6: alrightdariusru
slot #7: lovingyoueasyza
slot #8: sundazefloridag
slot #9: stopset
```

the final output of matchesFound is like this:

```
Item Number: 0 ****TOP OF HOUR****
Item Number: 1 d:\tocn\kelseaballerini-lovemelikeyoumeanit.wav
Item Number: 2 null
Item Number: 3 null
Item Number: 4 null
Item Number: 5 ****STOP SET****
Item Number: 6 null
```

... through 82.

```
public static String[] regionMatches(String[] directoryArray,
            String[] musicLogArray) throws InterruptedException {

        String[] matchesFound = new String[musicLogArray.length];
        String[] originalFileList = new String[directoryArray.length];

        for (int y = 0; y < directoryArray.length; y++) {

            originalFileList[y] = directoryArray[y];

            System.out.println("o value: " + originalFileList[y]);
            System.out.println("d value: " + directoryArray[y]);

        }

        for (int q = 0; q < originalFileList.length; q++) {
            originalFileList[q] = originalFileList[q].replaceAll(".wav", "");
            originalFileList[q] = originalFileList[q].replaceAll("\\\\", "");
            originalFileList[q] = originalFileList[q].replaceAll("[+.^:,]", "");
            originalFileList[q] = originalFileList[q].replaceAll("ctestmusic",
                    "");
            originalFileList[q] = originalFileList[q].replaceAll("tocn", "");

            originalFileList[q] = originalFileList[q].toLowerCase();
            String[] parts = originalFileList[q].split("-");
            originalFileList[q] = parts[1] + parts[0];
            System.out.println(originalFileList[q]);
        }

        for (int x = 0; x < musicLogArray.length; x++) {

            for (int y = 0; y < directoryArray.length; y++) {

                //System.out.println("value of x: " + x);
                //System.out.println("value of y: " + y);
                String searchMe = originalFileList[y];
                String findMe = musicLogArray[x];
                int searchMeLength = searchMe.length();
                int findMeLength = findMe.length();
                boolean foundIt = false;
                updateDisplay("searching term: " + "\"" + findMe+"\"");
                updateDisplay("comparing to: " + "\"" + searchMe + "\"");

                //for (int i = 0; i <= (searchMeLength - findMeLength); i++) {

                    if(searchMe.contains(findMe)){
                        updateDisplay("Match found!");
                        updateDisplay("value of findMe: " + findMe);
                        updateDisplay("value of searchMe: " + searchMe);
                        updateDisplay("value of y: " + y);
                        updateDisplay("value of x: " + x);

                        matchesFound[x] = directoryArray[y];
                        break;

//                  if (searchMe.regionMatches(i, findMe, 0, findMeLength)) {
//                      foundIt = true;
//                      updateDisplay("MATCH FOUND!: "
//                              + searchMe.substring(i, i + findMeLength));
//
//                      matchesFound[x] = directoryArray[y];
//
//                      break;
                    } else if (findMe.contains("stopset")){

                        matchesFound[x] = "****STOP SET****";
                        break;

                    } else if (findMe.contains("topofho")) {

                        matchesFound[x] = "****TOP OF HOUR****";
                        break;

                    }
                }
                //if (!foundIt) {
                //  updateDisplay("No match found.");

                //}

            }

        //}
        return matchesFound;
    }
```

Comment: This is probably not related to your problem, but it looks to me like the `break;` lines should have been removed when you removed the for loop.

Comment: In situations like this the first culprit to look for is if you have any whitespace before or after any of your strings, like newlines or spaces.

Comment: Also, if you really feel you isolated this down to one line of code, you could create a test program that contains only that one line to try to reproduce your problem. If the test program reproduces it, show us that instead of all your other code. If it doesn't reproduce it, then maybe the problem isn't that line.

Comment: Share your input file? Also try using `searchMe.contains(findMe.trim())`

Comment: It looks like you already have some good debugging print statements already in place; could you tell us what they tell you when you run the program?

Comment: If you are certain that `searchMe.contains(findMe)` should be true, then certainly you know what `searchMe` and `findMe` are.  Why not share them with us, rather than making us guess?  You could have asked this question in about 4 lines, instead of giving us a long method we can do nothing with since we don't have your input.

Answer (score 6):

It seems to me that your music directory has a bunch of unwanted d's in the file where you put the pieces back together.

searching term: "lovingyoueasyza"
comparing to: "lovingyoueasydzacbrownband"

The comparing to string does not contain the search term because after "easy" there is a "d" which ruins the search which is why you are having errors including artist names.

Answer (score 4):

Here:

```
searching term: "lovingyoueasyza"
comparing to: "lovingyoueasydzacbrownband"
```

In your second string, note that there is an **extra `d`** after easy.
So the second string does not contain the first string.

I think you are **adding an extra 'd'** when combining song name with the artist name.
The same thing is happening for all your other strings, e.g.

```
searching term: "onehellofanamen"
comparing to: "onehellofanamendbrantleygilbert"
```

which I suppose is `one hell of an amen`  + **the extra 'd'** + `brantley gilbert`.